# slick slider как убрать border

Tags: javascript, css, border, slick.js

Возможно ли в примере ниже убрать `border-right` у 1 и 2, 4 и 5. То есть, чтобы везде был border одинаковой ширины, а сейчас границы по центру в 2 раза. толще чем по бокам

*Пример:*

```js
jQuery(".regular").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="regular slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
  </div>
</section>
```

<sub>[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0v1p1b5/8/)</sub>

Испробовал кучу методов. Например:

```
.slick-list{
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
```

Но это все костыли, которые ломаются при адаптиве.

Comment: Проще всего, конечно, использовать цвет бордера такой же, как у фона, но вас, по всей видимости, такое решение не устраивает :)
А вопрос интересный.

Comment: да, суть в том чтобы убрать бордеры, а цвет и толщину сделал для наглядности

Answer (score 1):

Через `:nth-child` можно убрать:

```js
jQuery(".regular").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
}

/* Выделяем каждый 3 элемента и убираем границу у первого из них и второго */
.slick-slide:nth-child(3n+1), .slick-slide:nth-child(3n+2) {border-right: 0}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="regular slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
  </div>
</section>
```

Но выглядит всё равно кривовато, из за неровной работы скрипта

Answer (score 1):

Для первого слайда используется стиль `.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active`.
Казалось бы, хорошо, найдем способ найти и `.slick-last`.
Однако добавление `.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active {border-left:10px solid red}` решает проблему только частично - слайды расползаются по вертикали и не только, появляется "кривизна".

К сожалению, скрипт вообще плохо работает с расчетом границ, на что имеются жалобы.

[43 подтвержденных и до сих пор не закрытых бага](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/labels/Bug%3A%20Confirmed) говорят обо всем.

Поэтому мой ответ такой: используйте другой скрипт, отвечающий вашим потребностям.

Answer (score 0):

На будущее, если кто-то столкнулся с проблемой, сможет взять стили [с этого сайта](http://new.3259404.ru/catalog/chay_c310) (вдруг еще что-нибудь придумаю). Для этого нужно просмотреть не меньше 5 товаров, тогда появится блок "Вы недавно смотрели"( или блок [Похожие товары](http://new.3259404.ru/catalog/chay-tess-sunrise-sanrayz-chernyy-100-paketikov_i552baf6c08647)) Суть: убрать правый бордер у всех, задать паддинги и ширину на обертку(как в первом посте), а так же задать фиксированную ширину через импортант для каждого элемента слайда. Это я еще давно придумывал эвристическим подходом, а вчера хотел найти универсальное решение. Буду рад другим решениям. Спасибо, Yuri и labris, за ваши мнения и предложения.

Comment: Не уверен, что будет работать для примера в поставленном вопросе; и как будет вести себя фиксированная ширина при изменении размеров браузера?

Comment: @labris, да этот способ не работает на адаптиве, только если с жесткой привязкой по ширине, именно поэтому я и задал вопрос. пока так работает :)